# Crop mongo document with filter

Tags: django, mongodb, mongodb-query, djongo

The project stack is Django + MongoDB (djongo library).
I have order table with data structure like this

```json
{
  name:"Help",
  price:123,
  products:[
    {
      "_id":"some id",
      "organization":{
        "id":1
      }
    },
    {
      "_id":"some id2",
      "organization":{
        "id":2
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I get list order which has item in 'products' set where organization id field is equal 1?

When I will get this list how can I delete products set items where organization id field isn't equal 1?

So I should get something like this (Price field shouldn't be too)

```json
{
  name:"Help",
  products:[
    {
      "_id":"some id",
      "organization":{
        "id":1
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- `$filter` products and keep only those with `organization.id=1`
- remove price field (`$$REMOVE` is system variable, and if a field gets this value its removed)

*you can use project also it is the same, but `$set` leaves all other fields you possible have unchanged

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70496121-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set":
  {"price":"$$REMOVE",
   "products":
   {"$filter":
    {"input":"$products",
     "cond":{"$eq":["$$this.organization.id", 1]}}}}}])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solution helped me.

Comment: read mongodb documentation its very good with examples